# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac {\sin x} {x \cos^2 x} \mathrm d x$

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate:

> $$\int_0^{\pi/ 4} \frac {\sin x} {x \cos^2 x} \mathrm d x$$

Mathematica gives the numerical approximation:

$0.959926156626593638859649248036004150970933774605514278777212260466184427508$

I cannot find a closed form though. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an elegant integral!

Comment: @Integrals Do you think there exists a closed form? I might put a bounty on it...

Comment: I do think a closed form exists for this integral. I have been trying on this one. However, my view is slightly bias as I have a firm belief that all integrals have a closed form:)

Comment: @Oliver: Have you tried substituting the series of $\sin x$?

Comment: @WilliamHilbert I have tried series expansions but they aren't very nice.

Comment: So far, i've got this. And i don't know what to do next. And i forgot to write dx es. sorry for that.
$$\int \frac{sinx}{xcos^{2}x}dx=\int \frac{sinx}{x}tan{}'x\:dx=\frac{sin^{2}x}{xcosx}-\int \frac{xcosx-sinx}{x^{2}}tanx\:dx=\frac{sin^{2}x}{xcosx}-\int \frac{sinx}{x}+\int \frac{1-cos^{2}x}{x^{2}cosx}=\frac{sin^{2}x}{xcosx}-Si(x)+Si(x)+\frac{cosx}{x}+ \int\frac{1}{x^{2}cosx}=\frac{1}{xcosx}+\int \frac{1}{x^{2}cosx}$$

Comment: @Oliver, I get something like $$\frac{4}{\pi}(\sqrt{2}-1) + \frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}\log\left(\frac{4n+3}{4n+1}\right)$$ It is not very nice and I don't have any idea how to simplify it further, is that what you get?

Comment: @achillehui  I got a further simplification: $$ \frac{4}{\pi}\left(\sqrt2+\sum^{\infty}_{m=0}\frac{|E_{2m}|(\pi/4)^{2m}}{(2m-1)(2m)!}\right).$$
where $E_{2m}$ are [Euler numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number).

Comment: @ChenWang, hmm.. this is the same expansion as the one in Felix's answer. Unluckily, the presence of the Euler numbers make it hard to resum it to known special functions...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\sin\pars{x} \over x\cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\sin\pars{x} \over x\cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x}=
> \int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\sec\pars{x}\tan\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
> =\int_{x=0}^{x=\pi/4}\,{\dd\bracks{\sec\pars{x} -1}\over x}
> \\[3mm]&={4 \over \pi}\,\pars{\root{2} - 1}
> +\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\sec\pars{x} -1 \over x^{2}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={4 \over \pi}\,\pars{\root{2} - 1}
> +\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}{E_{2n} \over \pars{2n}!}
> \int_{0}^{\pi/4}x^{2n - 2}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large{4 \over \pi}\,\pars{\root{2} - 1}
> +\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}{E_{2n} \over \pars{2n}!\pars{2n - 1}}
> \pars{\pi \over 4}^{2n - 1}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{E_{n}}$ is an [Euler Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number).

Comment: Nice approach. +1

Comment: Well I wouldn't call it a closed form, and that's kind of the definition of Euler numbers, but it's probably the best that exists.

Comment: @Oliver Indeed, for a long time I struggled with several tricks. As you already said "it's probably the best that exists". Recently, I found that $\large \sec\left(x\right)$ Taylor series involves the Euler numbers. I saw many solutions in MSE that involves series. Thanks.