# Is there any problem on evaluating the indefinite integral that couldn't be solved?

Tags: calculus, integration

In another word, is there any indefinite integral that couldn't find another representation

Comment: Yes, there are lots.

Comment: @mjqxxxx - What is an example?

Comment: This is one of them:
[$$
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4} \frac {\sin x} {x \cos^2 x} \mathrm d x.
$$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773200/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-pi-4-frac-sin-x-x-cos2-x-mathrm-d-x)At least, how to solve it analytically is unknown yet. Wanna give a try? :)

Comment: One source of examples would be "cheating" by encoding unsolved problems as integral equalities. [Sometimes](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01056314) this might be even useful/natural.

Comment: There are general algorithms that give the indefinite integral in terms of given primitives, or show it can't be done. This is more the realm of symbolic computation.

Comment: Something else you could do is look at unanswered questions on SE : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-integrals?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,
$$\int \frac{1}{x-\sin x} dx$$

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%28%28x%2b1%29e%5Ex%29/%28x%281%2bxe%5Ex%29%29dx

$$\int \frac{(x+1)e^x}{x(1+xe^x)} dx$$

There should be a lot of these I think